# Sort a list of dictionaries while consolidating duplicates in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, search, python-2.7, merge

So I have a list of dictionaries like so:

```
data = [ { 
           'Organization' : '123 Solar',
           'Phone' : '444-444-4444',
           'Email' : '',
           'website' : 'www.123solar.com'
         }, {
           'Organization' : '123 Solar',
           'Phone' : '',
           'Email' : 'joey@123solar.com',
           'Website' : 'www.123solar.com'
         }, {
           etc...
         } ]
```

Of course, this is not the exact data. But (maybe) from my example here you can catch my problem. I have many records with the same "Organization" name, but not one of them has the complete information for that record.

Is there an *efficient* method for searching over the list, sorting the list based on the dictionary's first entry, and finally merging the data from duplicates to create a **unique** entry? (Keep in mind these dictionaries are quite large)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

data = [ {
           'Organization' : '123 Solar',
           'Phone' : '444-444-4444',
           'Email' : '',
           'website' : 'www.123solar.com'
         }, {
           'Organization' : '123 Solar',
           'Phone' : '',
           'Email' : 'joey@123solar.com',
           'Website' : 'www.123solar.com'
         },
         {
           'Organization' : '234 test',
           'Phone' : '111',
           'Email' : 'a@123solar.com',
           'Website' : 'b.123solar.com'
         },
         {
           'Organization' : '234 test',
           'Phone' : '222',
           'Email' : 'ac@123solar.com',
           'Website' : 'bd.123solar.com'
         }]


data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('Organization'))
result = {}
for key, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter('Organization')):
    result[key] = [item for item in group]

pprint(result)
```

prints:

```
{'123 Solar': [{'Email': '',
                'Organization': '123 Solar',
                'Phone': '444-444-4444',
                'website': 'www.123solar.com'},
               {'Email': 'joey@123solar.com',
                'Organization': '123 Solar',
                'Phone': '',
                'Website': 'www.123solar.com'}],
 '234 test': [{'Email': 'a@123solar.com',
               'Organization': '234 test',
               'Phone': '111',
               'Website': 'b.123solar.com'},
              {'Email': 'ac@123solar.com',
               'Organization': '234 test',
               'Phone': '222',
               'Website': 'bd.123solar.com'}]}
```

UPD:

Here's what you can do to group items into single dict:

```
for key, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter('Organization')):
    result[key] = {'Phone': [],
                   'Email': [],
                   'Website': []}
    for item in group:
        result[key]['Phone'].append(item['Phone'])
        result[key]['Email'].append(item['Email'])
        result[key]['Website'].append(item['Website'])
```

then, in `result` you'll have:

```
{'123 Solar': {'Email': ['', 'joey@123solar.com'],
               'Phone': ['444-444-4444', ''],
               'Website': ['www.123solar.com', 'www.123solar.com']},
 '234 test': {'Email': ['a@123solar.com', 'ac@123solar.com'],
              'Phone': ['111', '222'],
              'Website': ['b.123solar.com', 'bd.123solar.com']}}
```

Comment: I tested your code, and it's not exactly what I need. Thanks for showing me the sort, that was amazing. I am looking for a way to combine all the dictionaries with the same organization name into one dictionary in the same list.

Comment: Sure, you can make one dictionary from this. Just use that `group` variable.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an efficient method for searching over the list, sorting the list based on the dictionary's first entry, and finally merging the data from duplicates to create a unique entry?

Yes, but there's an even more efficient method without searching and sorting. Just build up a dictionary as you go along:

```
datadict = {}
for thingy in data:
    organization = thingy['Organization']
    datadict[organization] = merge(thingy, datadict.get(organization, {}))
```

Now you've making a linear pass over the data, doing a constant-time lookup for each one. So, it's better than any sorted solution by a factor of O(log N). It's also one pass instead of multiple passes, and it will probably have lower constant overhead besides.

---

It's not clear exactly what you want to do to merge the entries, and there's no way anyone can write the code without knowing what rules you want to use. But here's a simple example:

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    for key, value in d2.items():
        if not d1.get(key):
            d1[key] = value
    return d1
```

In other words, for each item in `d2`, if `d1` already has a truthy value (like a non-empty string), leave it alone; otherwise, add it.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a `merge` function?

Comment: That's the easy part; I assumed you already knew how to do that. But I'll edit the answer to show an example:

Comment: I'm new to Python..sorry if I seem dunce.